SSE not working with Rust Yew, different errors occuring
I recently tried to connect my Yew frontend app to an actix-web SSE server I use to send events to the page. I tried different approaches and crates like EventSource from "web_sys", "sse_client" and "gloo_net" but none of them worked.
Sometimes I got CORS errors but now I only get a connection error by the Browser.
For a while the Browser console also said, my callback function got either dropped or was called recursively.
I know that my SSE server works at least in some way. With curl I can connect without problem and receive all events that are emitted. So the problem should be related to my frontend code.
I uploaded a working example with server and client to GitHub using gloo_net crate:
https://github.com/heureka-code/sse-test
This is the part of the frontend that matters:
#[function_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    use wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local;
    let src = gloo_net::eventsource::futures::EventSource::new("//localhost:9000/sse"); // <--- Two Slashes made the difference
    use futures::StreamExt; 

    log::info!("{src:?}"); // (Before) status: Connecting

    if let Ok(mut event_source) = src {
        let mut stream1 = event_source.subscribe("test-event").unwrap();

        spawn_local(async move {
            log::info!("{event_source:?}"); // (Before) status: Connecting
            log::info!("First: {:?}", stream1.next().await); // (Before) Some(Err(ConnectionError))
            log::info!("{event_source:?}"); // status: Closed
            while let Some(Ok((event_type, msg))) = stream1.next().await {
                log::warn!("New message: {event_type} {msg:?}");
            }
            log::info!("Finished");
        });
        log::info!("After spawn");
    }

    html!()
}

This is the SSE route of the server:
use actix_web::{get, Responder};
use actix_web_lab::sse;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

#[get("/sse")]
async fn stream_updates() -> impl Responder {
    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(10);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        for i in 0..10 {
            let _ = tx
                .send(sse::Data::new(i.to_string()).event("test-event").into())
                .await;
            sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        }
    });

    let sse = sse::Sse::from_infallible_receiver(rx).with_retry_duration(Duration::from_secs(10));
    let sse = sse
        .customize()
        .append_header(("access-control-allow-origin", "*"))
        .append_header(("access-control-allow-headers", "content-type"));
    return sse;
}

I tried different libraries but never received helpful error messages.
You can start the server inside it's directory as normal with cargo run.
The frontend code can be executed like explained here:
https://yew.rs/docs/getting-started/introduction
When running you can look at the browser's console or with curl at
localhost:9000/sse
If my system is relevant for the problem, I'm using Linux and Firefox.
Maybe it's a simple solution but I don't know what to try next. Maybe someone could help?
EDIT:
Now with two slashes at the start of the connection url it works at least in some way. I receive messages but there is still an error message without detail displayed by the browser within the console.
Something about the connection got to the server got disrupted while connecting to the website...
